# How to parse datetime data in a json string in BigQuery

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I am trying to parse a datetime column inside a json string in Bigquery. So far BQ only return the year part (as a number). For example, this script

```
select json_extract(json_data, '$.application_date') from (select '{"user_id":"10000561","application_date":2020-08-03 12:55:21}' as json_data)
```

returns 2020 instead of the desired result 2020-08-03 12:55:21.

Please help me. How can I fix this?

Comment: Your json data doesn't seem to be valid. Would you try it again with `{"user_id":"10000561","application_date":"2020-08-03 12:55:21"}` ? Also, you have to use `JSON_VALUE()` instead of `json_extract`.

Comment: If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [json_extract_scalor](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_extract_scalar)(), and then [parse_datetime](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#parse_datetime)() on the returning string.

Using your example:

```
select parse_datetime("%F %T", json_extract_scalar(json_data, '$.application_date')) 
from (
   select '{"user_id":"10000561","application_date":"2020-08-03 12:55:21"}' 
   as json_data
)
```

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement, [json_value](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_value) can be used to parse date and time from the json string.You can try the below code to get the expected output.

**Code**

```
select parse_datetime("%F %T", json_value(json_data, '$.application_date')) as date_and_time
from (
  select '{"user_id":"10000561","application_date":"2020-08-03 12:55:21"}'
  as json_data
)
```

**Output**

[image]